# JPA OneToMany relationship: deleting child records does not delete correct id

Tags: hibernate, jpa, parent-child, one-to-many, cascading-deletes

I have a parent entity that can have multiple child entities. I get the parent and child data from it's repository api endpoint in a JSON format. I can add new child records and modify existing ones by modifying the JSON and sending a put request to the parent's repository. However, if I try to delete a child record, it takes the removed record's id, and assigns it to the next child entity, so forth and so on until the child record with the highest id is removed. Note the data for the child record besides their id are correct. It's very hard to explain but hopefully some visuals will help.

```java
@Entity
class Parent {

  @Id
  private String parentId;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="parent", orphanRemoval=true, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Child> child;

  // public getters and setters and some other properties omitted
}

@Entity
class Child {
  
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  private String number;

  private String parentId;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="parent_id", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable=false)
  @JsonIgnore
  private Parent parent;
  
  // public getters and setters and some other properties omitted
}

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, String> {

    Facility findByParentId(String parentId);

}
```

Relevant child data before

| id | number | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3697 | 1 | TEST12345 |
| 3704 | 2 | TEST12345 |
| 3707 | 3 | TEST12345 |
| 3706 | 4 | TEST12345 |

GET request to http://localhost:8090/api/parents/search/findByParentId?ParentId=TEST12345 yields the following response

```
{
  "parentId": "TEST12345",
  "child": [
    { "id": 3697, "number": 1, "parentId": "TEST12345" },
    { "id": 3704, "number": 2, "parentId": "TEST12345" },
    { "id": 3707, "number": 3, "parentId": "TEST12345" },
    { "id": 3706, "number": 4, "parentId": "TEST12345" }
  ]
}
```

Removing the second record (id: 3704), with a PUT request to: http://localhost:8090/api/parents/TEST12345 and the body

```
{
  "parentId": "TEST12345",
  "child": [
    { "id": 3697, "number": 1, "parentId": "TEST12345" },
    { "id": 3707, "number": 3, "parentId": "TEST12345" },
    { "id": 3706, "number": 4, "parentId": "TEST12345" }
  ]
}
```

Relevant child data after

| id | number | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3697 | 1 | TEST12345 |
| 3704 | 3 | TEST12345 |
| 3707 | 4 | TEST12345 |

You see the delete data is correct but the id's are not. Hibernate actually does 2 update statements then a delete statement. Note if I delete the latest id (in this case 3707), the record will delete correctly without modifying any others. It seems to only update id's that come after the deleted record's. From my understanding the child's id should be the authority for the records as designated by the @Id annotation. I have no clue why this behavior is happening and have found no related issues. My id types are consistent with my database column types and the getters and setters.

Expected result would be

| id | number | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3697 | 1 | TEST12345 |
| 3707 | 3 | TEST12345 |
| 3706 | 4 | TEST12345 |

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would appear the merge is confusing things - do you have some equals/hash implementation that is incorrectly associating things, or maybe you've test code that looks up entities and change the ID values in the entities? IDs should never be modified once assigned - you'd have to put this through with a debugger, possibly calling find on the parent instance and checking what is returned before calling the save functionality to figure it out.

Comment: I don't have anything that modifies ids nor do I modify them. I only splice a record from an array. I don't know how to debug it either. I'm using JpaRepositories built in endpoint functionality so I dont actually have any api code I can iterate through. It's all handled by Jpa. One thing is, I don't think the IDs are really getting modified per se. The hibernate sql log shows its updating every other value of the record besides the ID, and then just deleting the left over record, if that makes sense. It's just not listening to the id I pass it, but only for deletes